# How to implement Sinch on production

Tags: java, android

Sinch is working fine with my app (debug.apk), but the problem appears if I run the app which is downloaded from playstore (release.aab).

This is my logcat, Im using Java

```
11-21 06:18:51.321 3593-5039/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 8096 [11-21 06:18:51.329]
11-21 06:18:54.331 32714-32714/? A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1337] No pending exception expected: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.sinch.android.rtc.internal.natives.HttpRequest" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/dealmagnet.com-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/dealmagnet.com-1/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk", zip file "/data/app/dealmagnet.com-1/split_config.en.apk", zip file "/data/app/dealmagnet.com-1/split_config.xxxhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/dealmagnet.com-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/dealmagnet.com-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/dealmagnet.com-1/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/dealmagnet.com-1/split_config.en.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/dealmagnet.com-1/split_config.xxxhdpi.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
11-21 06:18:54.331 32714-32714/? A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1337]   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
11-21 06:18:54.331 32714-32714/? A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1337]   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:511)
11-21 06:18:54.331 32714-32714/? A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1337]   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:469)
11-21 06:18:54.331 32714-32714/? A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1337]   at java.lang.String java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String) (Runtime.java:-2)
11-21 06:18:54.331 32714-32714/? A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1337]   at java.lang.String java.lang.Runtime.doLoad(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Runtime.java:435)
11-21 06:18:54.331 32714-32714/? A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1337]   at void java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Runtime.java:370)
11-21 06:18:54.331 32714-32714/? A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1337]   at void java.lang.System.loadLibrary(java.lang.String) (System.java:1076)
11-21 06:18:54.331 32714-32714/? A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1337]   at void c.e.c.h.d(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) (:1)
11-21 06:18:54.331 32714-32714/? A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1337]   at void c.e.c.h.c(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, c.e.c.e) (:-1)
11-21 06:18:54.331 32714-32714/? A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1337]   at void c.e.a.a.j.c.z.a.a(android.content.Context) (:5)
11-21 06:18:54.331 32714-32714/? A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1337]   at void c.e.a.a.j.c.i.<init>(android.content.Context, c.e.a.a.j.c.q, c.e.a.a.j.c.j, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, c.e.a.a.j.c.d, java.lang.String, c.e.a.a.j.c.a0.c, c.e.a.a.j.a, boolean, boolean, int) (:1)
11-21 06:18:54.331 32714-32714/? A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1337]   at c.e.a.a.e c.e.a.a.b.b() (:1)
```

And this is the documentation from the Sinch, What is the class do I need to use >> myApiService

```
sinchClient.addSinchClientListener(...);

public void onRegistrationCredentialsRequired(SinchClient client,
                                              ClientRegistration registrationCallback) {

    myApiService.getAuthorizedSignatureForUser("<user id>", new OnCompletedCallback() {
        public void onCompleted(String signature, long sequence) {

            registrationCallback.register(signature, sequence);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer here, Sinch is not working fine because I tried to split my APK to reduce sizes and I used proguard to obfuscate the code, but the error arrived here,

I have to modify my proguard rules.